# Laravel 4 500 Internal Server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

first I want to say I have read and tried all the other questions here with the same title but I am still getting the same error 500.

I have XAMPP local and everything works ok, the problem is when I upload the site to my webhosting.

index is in public folder and works fine, but when I tried to go to /finder I get the 500 page

this is the structure of my files:

```
public/index.php its ok

app/views/finder.php 500 error
```

this is my route file:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});

Route::get('finder', 'ApartmentsController@finder');
```

and this is my htaccess

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

any advice?

thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

the problem is not in htaccess, the problem is in the method finder(), exactly here in the query builder, but why it works local???:

```
$searchResult=DB::table('books')->join('apartments', 'apartment_id', '=', 'apartments.id');

    if(((count($tipo)==NULL)||(count($tipo)==1)) && $tipo[0]==''){

    }else if (count($tipo)==1){
            $searchResult->where('apt_type','=',$tipo[0]);

            }else{

                $searchResult->where(function($query){


    //Here is the problem, if I delete this piece of code everything works                  $query->where('apt_type','=',Input::get( 'tipo' )[0]);

                        for ($i=1;$i<count(Input::get( 'tipo' ));$i++){

                            $query->orwhere('apt_type','=',Input::get( 'tipo' )[$i]);
                        }


                });
            }
```

Comment: Post `ApartmentsController@finder` class and method as it is. The problem is in your class.

Comment: Yes I haven't see that, I delete the function finder() content and the 500 error disappear but why is then working local? the code is searching through a complex juqery builder to the database, what could it be wrong?

Comment: What URL are you trying to access? What lines appear in your webserver log file? What happens when you access `public/index.php/finder`?

Comment: Hi Antonio, as Sheikh show me there is a problem with the controller method, I can't see where because is working local I thought it was a problem with the htaccess but if I delete the method finder() content the error 500 dissapear.

Comment: I have updated the question with the piece of code with the problem, why it works local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `Input::get( 'tipo' )[$i]` is only possible in PHP 5.4+. If your host is PHP 5.3, it won't work.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. *foo()[0]*.